# How to rewrite a file in internal storage in android?

Tags: android, file-io

Can i rewrite a file or check is there or not that created by the app? 
Can i create a file with the same name of the other file that created by the another app? 
Must i pass the path of file when writing openFileInput(name) or openFileOutput

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
String yourFilePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "hello.txt";
File file = new File( yourFilePath );
if(file.exists()) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i asked abouth internal storage?